# Where can I find the Comment button?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I am having trouble finding the button to comment on existing questions/answers(I'm being criticized on some stackExchange-sites because I posted comments as answers). Where can I find it? Or do I need special privileges before being able to comment?

Comment: Just wait until you gain 50 reputation (not hard to achieve, just find some things to answer) then you can leave comments and become more active part of the community.

Answer (score 1):

According to your profile, as of this writing you have 28 reputation on Stack Overflow. You need 50 to be able to leave comments on other people's posts. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) for the privilege to comment everywhere.